# Cannot customize Solution Explorer project context menu in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide-customization

I'm trying to customize that context menu which comes up when you right click the project in the Solution Explorer.

When I goto: Tools - Customize - Commands - Context Menu (radio button) - Project and Solution Context Menus | Project (drop down)

I get nothing in the "controls:" list. I can modify other context menus starting with "Project and Solution Context Menus" but none of them is the right one.

Any ideas? Currently I have ReSharper, PowerTools and StyleCop installed, but I have installed and uninstalled bunch of other addins (dotTrace, CodeIt.Right, VisualHG, DevExpress, random stuff from Extension Manager).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling ReSharper 5.0 fixed the problem.